# Full text search not work with Prefix 'the'

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a problem building a query with full text search. 
In my database there a company table with name column, and one of the company name is 'the acclaimed software company'

If I run the query below, I **cannot** get any result:

```
SELECT *
FROM  [dbo].[Company]
WHERE contains([CompanyName], '"the*" and "acclaimed*" and  "software*" and "company*"')
```

If I run the query without '"the*"', I get the correct result:

```
SELECT *
FROM  [dbo].[Company]
WHERE contains([CompanyName], '"acclaimed*" and  "software*" and "company*"')
```

Someone could help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"The" is considered a noise word and is thus ignored.

How to configure and manage those, can be found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15)